# How to show distinct sender id from conversation

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, distinct

Updated Question:

My **private_messages** database structure is like this:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+--------+------------+
| id | text  | byuid | touid | unread |  timesent  |
+----+-------+-------+-------+--------+------------+
|  1 | Hi    |     1 |     4 |      1 | 1514764805 |
|  2 | hello |     1 |     4 |      1 | 1514764804 |
|  3 | hlw   |     1 |     4 |      1 | 1514764803 |
|  4 | good  |     2 |     4 |      1 | 1514764802 |
|  5 | fine  |     3 |     4 |      0 | 1514764801 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+--------+------------+
```

My all_users_table is:

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | name  | pass |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | user1 |  123 |
|  2 | user2 |  112 |
|  3 | user3 |  124 |
|  4 | user4 |  258 |
|  5 | user5 |  315 |
+----+-------+------+
```

My current SQL code is

```
$sql = "SELECT
a.name, b.id, b.byuid, b.unread, b.starred FROM all_users_table a
INNER JOIN private_messages b ON a.id = b.byuid
WHERE b.touid='4' AND starred='0'
ORDER BY b.timesent DESC, b.unread
LIMIT $limit_start, $items_per_page
";
```

Which Print Like below:

```
1
1
1
2
3
```

All I want is to (For touid = 4)

1. print all unique byuid as a output.
2. Order By Unread DESC
3. Order By timesent DESC
4. Limit 0, 2 (for pagination purpose)

Output should be:

```
1
2
```

Can anyone help me please ? I tried Group By but it shows empty results.

Comment: have you tried to do the group by on your all_users_table table?

Comment: Yes I did but it shows empty result.

Comment: use proper structure to show the data,this is not helpful

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Structure updated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT
a.name, b.id, b.byuid, b.unread, b.starred FROM all_users_table a
INNER JOIN private_messages b ON a.id = b.byuid
WHERE b.touid='".$myid."' AND starred='0' GROUP BY a.name 
ORDER BY b.timesent DESC, b.unread
LIMIT $limit_start, $items_per_page";
```

Try this one with **GROUP BY CLAUSE**

Answer (score 0):

If you need  not duplicated rows  you should use DISTINCT clause

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT
    a.name, b.id, b.byuid, b.unread, b.starred 
    FROM all_users_table a
    INNER JOIN private_messages b ON a.id = b.byuid
    WHERE b.touid='".$myid."' AND starred='0'
    ORDER BY b.timesent DESC, b.unread
    LIMIT $limit_start, $items_per_page";
```

*(the use of group by for avoid duplicated  row in absence of aggregation function as  SUM() or MAX() is deprecated  in sql and in the most recent version of mySQL  generate error)*

But looking to your updated  data  you are not looking for the distinct result but at the result for the most recent sent values 
and for this you don't need distinct but a join between al the columns you need and a subselect that retrive the sot recent  value for byuid

```
    select  a.name, b.id, b.byuid, b.unread, b.starred 
    FROM all_users_table a
    INNER JOIN private_messages b ON a.id = b.byuid A
    INNER JOIN (
      select byuid, max(timesent) max_sent
      from private_messages 
      WHERE b.touid= 4 
      group by byuid
    ) t on t.byuid = b.byuid and t.max_sent = b.timesent
    ORDER BY  b.timesent DESC, b.unread 
    LIMIT $limit_start, $items_per_page
```

Comment: The query print empty / blank result :(

Comment: The distinct clause just remove duplicated  rows  so ... if you have not result thisisi not related to the DISTINCT  .. (you can try removing the word DISTINCT)  .. so check better you code  ..  and don't use / add  group by  .. this can raise an error and return empty result set

Comment: Still not working. I have updated the question and explained elaborately . Please check.

Comment: answer update .. with a new suggestion ..but you should note that . your data sample is really different respect to your original question  ..

Comment: Thank you for your reply @scaisEdge , Unfortunately it returns an empty result :(

Comment: asnwer updated . strictly related  to your data sample  ..  . (chek better)

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT
    a.name, b.id, b.byuid, b.unread, b.starred
FROM all_users_table a
LEFT JOIN private_messages b ON a.id = b.byuid
WHERE b.touid = '".$myid."' AND starred = '0'
ORDER BY b.timesent DESC, b.unread
LIMIT $limit_start, $items_per_page"
```

Comment: Please provide context / reasoning for your answer and not just include a code sample. Also, it would be good to point out the difference between the original INNER join and your LEFT join.

Comment: Sorry unfortunately its not working. I have updated the question bro can you check now please ?

Comment: you have not mentioned 'starred' in table 'private_messages'
please give correct data